# Solving system of multivariate quadratic equations

Tags: polynomials, vectors, quadratics, nonlinear-system

I have a system of quadratic equations:

$$\cos(\theta_1) = \frac{u_1\cdot u' + v_1\cdot v'+w_1\cdot w'}{\sqrt{u_1^2+v_1^2+w_1^2}\sqrt{u'^2+v'^2+w'^2}}$$

$$\cos(\theta_2) = \frac{u_2\cdot u' + v_2\cdot v'+w_2\cdot w'}{\sqrt{u_2^2+v_2^2+w_2^2}\sqrt{u'^2+v'^2+w'^2}}$$

$$\cos(\theta_3) = \frac{u_3\cdot u' + v_3\cdot v'+w_3\cdot w'}{\sqrt{u_3^2+v_3^2+w_3^2}\sqrt{u'^2+v'^2+w'^2}}$$

In which I'm trying to solve for $u'$, $v'$, $w'$ (all other quantities are known). Is there any standard approach for solving this system? Specifically something I could code in python? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you meant that $a = (u,v,w)$ and $b = (u',v',w')$ , right ??

Comment: @HosamH Yes but also $u=(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ , $v=(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ , $w=(w_1, w_2, w_3)$ which would be necessary to determine $u', v', w'$ (3 equations, 3 unknowns), right?

Comment: That does not make any sense. The components of a vector cannot be other vectors.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Let me know if my edit makes more sense - I tried to make it more explicit

Comment: Knowing only the angles from three vectors (even if you have that they are linearly independent) is not enough to solve for the three parameters you want.

Comment: This question is very confusing to me.  I've never seen anything like it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi can you explain why? Does “n equations, n unknowns” go out the window with non-linearity?

Comment: @SterlingButters of course it does, that was *specifically* a property of linear equations only, which comes from linear algebra. Here in this situation though, it's intuitively obvious that only knowing the angular locations of a point (vector) in space could never tell you about its magnitude.

Comment: Also your formulation is incorrect - your three vectors should be $a_1 = (u_1,v_1,w_1),\cdots$ not $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3),\cdots$

Comment: @NinadMunshi how so? If it was a linear system I would need 3 values for u, v, and w. I understand why that wouldn’t work now but the formulation should still hold

Comment: If $(u' ,v' ,w')$ solves your equation then so is $(cu', cv', cw')$ for any $c\neq 0.$ So your equation has either no solution or infinitely many, latter of which you can characterize probably geometrically if you convert things to dot products.

Comment: @dezdichado what constraints can one impose on such a system that might force a unique solution?

Comment: I went through your post history, are you trying to code up a version of MCNP?

Comment: you are given three unit vectors and you want to find another vector which makes three prescribed angle with the given vectors. Geometrically, you are asking when does three cones emanating from the origin in $3D$ space has a unique intersection ? 

Whenever there is an intersection, it will be at least an infinite ray, or two, or four, or some lines and a conic section etc. Check https://www.grad.hr/geomteh3d/prodori/prodor_stst_eng.html#:~:text=Every%20two%20cones%20with%20a,the%20vertex%20of%20the%20cones. for example.

Comment: @NinadMunshi wow, I’m surprised you were able to gather that I was even dealing with MNCP. Actually what I am trying to do is estimate surface normals based on particle u,v,w, cos(theta) parameters generated with PTRAC surface collision events (which effectively creates a point cloud from which I’m an trying to perform surface reconstruction).

Comment: @dezdichado you’ve given me an idea maybe. How/is it possible to generate an array of points along the circumference of the base of the cone created by the angle between a set of vectors $(u_1, v_1, w_1)$ and $(u’, v’, w’)$? I.e., how could vary/parametrize $(u’, v’, w’)$ to generate these points along the circumference of the cone base?